# UMP of Folded Normal, Finding the Critical Value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,...,X_n$  be a random sample from the folded normal distribution with the density...

$f(x)= \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \theta^{-1} e^{(-x^{2} \theta^{-2})/2}$ for $x>0$ and $\theta>0$, 0 otherwise.

The question asks...

Find the UMP for test size $\alpha$ for $H_0:\theta = \theta_0$ vs. $H_0:\theta > \theta_0$. Determine the critical region for the value.

So the likelihood ratio is...
$$\dfrac{L(f(x,\theta_1))}{L(f(x,\theta_0))}= \bigg(\dfrac{\theta_1}{\theta_0}\bigg)^{-n} exp\bigg[{\sum{x^{2}_{i}}\frac{\theta_{0}^{-2}-\theta_{1}^{-2}}{2}} \bigg]$$

We know the UMP exists because the function is decreasing in $\sum x_{i}^{2}= T(x)$. So we reject the null if $T(x)<k$.

I am unsure about how to find $k$ because I do not know how to find the distribution of $T(x)$. Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you were to replace each $x_i$ by $z_i=x_iU_i$ where $U_i$ are independently distributed with equiprobable values in $\{-1,1\},$ you would find that (a) the $z_i$ have a Normal$(0,\theta)$ distribution while (b) $T(x)=T(z)$. Therefore you need to compute the distribution of the sum of squares of iid zero-mean Normal distributions. That should be familiar.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the idea, is there anywhere you can direct me to for an example?

Comment: Example of what?  A discussion of the replacement I describe appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27097. The sums of squares of Normals are discussed almost anywhere [the $\chi^2$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is mentioned.  Perhaps the example you seek can be found in one of those two places.

Comment: whuber has explained exactly the rather trivial idea needed to reduce this to a much simpler problem. The squares of your random variables $X_i^2$ have a distribution that is straightforward to find by the approach he suggested, it's like two lines of argument (most of which he already gave you).